# PHP query cannot select records that are between 1 week and 2 weeks old

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select records from a MySQL table that are between 1 and 2 weeks old The table has a date column. There is a date that is 10 days old but the query is ignoring it. Can you help please? Here is the query I am using:

```
$week2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM apps WHERE (user = '" 
.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and date BETWEEN ( DATE_SUB( NOW(), 
INTERVAL 2 WEEK), DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK )");
```

If I make the date less than a week old, I can select the record no problem with:

```
$week1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM apps WHERE (user = '" .
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
ORDER BY id DESC limit 1");
```

Comment: **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in new applications. It's dangerous by default unless you use `mysql_real_escape_string`, where if you forget even one parameter, you can get destroyed. [Use PDO or mysqli](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to keep yourself safe.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `BETWEEN` incorrectly.

Try

```
DATE BETWEEN x AND y
```

You can pass in a string as the dates also:

```
<?php
    $startDate = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 14, date('Y')));
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 7, date('Y')));

    $query = "... AND DATE BETWEEN '" . $startDate . "' AND '" . $endDate . "'";
```

Also, to echo tadman's comment, you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I replaced the comma with AND but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Done it! Took out the left bracket just before the first DATE_SUB. Thanks for your help guys anyway

Comment: PDO and mysqli? I'll try to find out more about them. I thought mysql_real_escape_string was the way to fight sql injection.

Comment: It's deprecated. No longer supported.